# Error adding a figure with multiples subfigures

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I would like to include a figure made by 2 or more subfigures.
This is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figuras/fig1}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figuras/fig2}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{subfigure}
    \quad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figuras/fig3}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
```

And I have imported the following packages:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{setspace}\singlespacing
```

I have this error in all \caption lines:

> Missing \endcsname inserted. \caption{Caption}
>   Extra \endcsname. \caption{Caption}

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please, make a small complete example of code that reproduces the problem. As far as I can see, the code will *not* break, with a standard class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mwe (minimal working example) below i composed from yours code fragments, in which i made the following changes:

- add `demo` option to `graphicx` (which generate black boxes instead of yours images which i haven't)
- add package `lipsum` for dummy text in test document
- replace `\quad` width `\hfill` which equidistantly place images between left and right text border
- to code add some codes which may be helpful to you
  complete *mwe* (minimal working example) is:

  ```
  \documentclass[english]{book}
  % \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % better to use \usepackage[utf]{inputenc}
                                  % which is newest version of document classes default
  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \usepackage{makeidx}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}         % in the real document remove option "demo"
  %\usepackage{latexsym}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{eucal}
  %\usepackage{setspace}\singlespacing

  \usepackage{lipsum}                 % for dummy text, remove in the real document
  \begin{document}
  \lipsum[1-5]
      \begin{figure}[htb]
  %\centering
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../figuras/fig1}
          \caption{sub caption}
      \end{subfigure}
      \hfill
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../figuras/fig2}
          \caption{sub caption}
      \end{subfigure}
      \hfill
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{../figuras/fig3}
          \caption{sub caption}
      \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Main caption}
      \end{figure}
  \lipsum[6-10]
  \end{document}
  ```

which gives:

[image]

from above *mwe* follows, that its code not cause any error. since log file of your document is unknown, it is difficult to say, from where is your error. for further help, please merge your document fragments in one small but complete document like in above *mwe* and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{setspace}
\singlespacing
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figuras/fig1}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figuras/fig2}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{subfigure}
\quad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../figuras/fig3}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am getting the following output for your source code, as I am not having the images. The screenshot is attached for your reference.

[image]

Edit 2: Alternate Solution using `SubFloat` Environment (Figures with 13 Subfigures).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{1} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-a}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{2} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{3} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-c}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{4} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{5} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{6} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-c}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{7} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{8} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{9} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-a}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{10} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{11} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-c}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{12} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}
\mbox{\subfloat[]{\label{13} \includegraphics[height=2.3cm]{example-image-b}}}


\caption{Normal Models. \protect\subref{subfig:1} SLR. \protect\subref{subfig:2} MLR. \protect\subref{subfig:3} SWR. \protect\subref{subfig:4} OLS. \protect\subref{5} OLS. \protect\subref{6} OS. \protect\subref{7} Ok. \protect\subref{8} hi. \protect\subref{9} hey. \protect\subref{10} MSD. \protect\subref{11} LPY. \protect\subref{12} MSY. \protect\subref{13} Hello.}
\label{fig}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what did you change? It seems to be the same...

Comment: You run it. I am getting no error. I have added the `\documentclass{article}`, also I have embedded your code inside the `\begin{document} \end{document}` fragment.

Comment: @Sergio See the edit in the answer.

Comment: I see. However, I cant change the document class to article becouse I was using book.

Comment: Okay. Change `\documentclass{book}` from `\documentclass{article}`. The code will work. See my edit in the above answer.

Comment: Yeah, sure, it works. But I cant change it becouse I am using book style... Is there any other way to use subcations and subfigures with book style?

Comment: See my recent edit!

Comment: I have the following error : Undefined control sequence. ...egraphics[height=2.3cm]{../figuras/fig2}}}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91247/discussion-between-siba-mishra-and-sergio-cavero).

Comment: Format the source carefully.